# Lodash merging arrays and handling duplicates

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays:

```
var a = [
    {aId: 1, name: "a1"}, 
    {aId: 2, name: "a2"}
];
var b = [
    {parentId: 1, description: "b1"}, 
    {parentId: 1, description: "b2"}, 
    {parentId: 2, description: "b3"}
];
```

I want to merge these arrays based on the parentId === aId;

I did:

```
var c = _.map(a, function(obj) {
    return _.assign(obj, _.find(b, {parentId: obj.aId}));
})
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j870pqf4/)

This works as expected, but I need it to handle duplicates - when this finds a match, it correctly merges it, but I instead need it to push the mergee into a new property, instead of merging.

What I get:

```
[ 
    {aId: 1, name: "a1", description: "b1"}, 
    {aId: 2, name: "a2", description: "b3"}
]
```

What I want:

```
[ 
    {
        aId: 1, 
        name: "a1", 
        b: [
            {parentId: 1, description: "b1"}, 
            {parentId: 1, description: "b2"}
        ]
     }, 
     {
        aId: 2, 
        name: "a2", 
        b: [
            {parentId: 2, description: "b1"}
        ]
     }
]
```

The common property can of course be omitted;

Comment: Use `_.filter` instead of `_.find` so that you get all the matching results into an array and update your mapping accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Edit

While this answer is very helpful and satisfies the original question to an extent, there's some discussion regarding mutation in the comments, which can cause unexpected behaviour, for example when using redux, or other libraries that rely on immutable state.

The original answer uses `_.assign` which causes the mutation.  The below uses the es6 spreads operator to return new objects into a new array.

```
const a = [{aId: 1, name: "a1"}, {aId: 2, name: "a2"}];
const b = [{parentId: 1, description: "b1"}, {parentId: 1, description: "b2"}, {parentId: 2, description: "b3"}];

const c = _.map(a, (obj) => 
  ({ ...obj, ...{ b: _.filter(b, {parentId: obj.aId}) }});

console.log('mimick original', c);
```

### Original Answer:

Your code is almost done; in the [_.assign()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) you can pass an object with a property `b` equal to the result of [_.filter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) instead of [_.find()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find):

```
{
  b: _.filter(b, {parentId: obj.aId})
}
```

Note that [_.find()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find) returns the matched element, else undefined and [_.filter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter) returns the new filtered array.

Code:

```js
var a = [{aId: 1, name: "a1"}, {aId: 2, name: "a2"}],
    b = [{parentId: 1, description: "b1"}, {parentId: 1, description: "b2"}, {parentId: 2, description: "b3"}];

_.map(a, function(obj) {
  return _.assign(obj, {
    b: _.filter(b, {parentId: obj.aId})
  });
});

console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems the _.map has modified the original array, there is no need for c

Comment: I think its the assign operation thats causing the mutation, could this be replaced with es6 spread?

Comment: @bigmadwolf yes sure, you can edit the answer.. It will be welcome. Thanks in advance